# How to Deploy SQL Server Analysis Services Project to a different domain?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, deployment, ssas

What is the best way to deploy an analysis services project database to a different domain. I have network access to that domain (I am able to ping it).

When I try to deploy the SSAS project to a live server in a different domain I get the following error:

> Error 8   The project could not be
>   deployed to the 'SERVER' server
>   because of the following connectivity
>   problems :  A connection cannot be
>   made. Ensure that the server is
>   running.  To verify or update the name
>   of the target server, right-click on
>   the project in Solution Explorer,
>   select Project Properties, click on
>   the Deployment tab, and then enter the
>   name of the server.       0   0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create an xmla file, copy it to the server and run it from SSMS locally on the server in question.

the xmla script can be generated using the

[Analysis Services Deployment Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162758.aspx)